# Remove UIView from ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiview

I have One view controller and in this view controller I have another sub view. How can I remove this sub view. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if([subview superView])
  {
  `[subview removeFromSuperview];`
}

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your subview name is tempView then use this

```
[tempView removeFromSuperview];
```